# Need to automate SSIS package execution with an Oracle source

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have SQL server 2019 standard edition. I have an SSIS package I am trying to run through the agent but I am getting an error stating that It cannot execute the package because I have an Oracle source and it requires enterprise edition. I do not need any of the enterprise edition features so it does not justify the cost.

I am using the SQL server Oracle connector. Is there anything else I can go to get around this besides buying enterprise edition?

I created an ssis data flow with an Oracle source. I imported the package into the SSIS package store. It runs successfully in our test environment (developer edition) but it errors out in production (standard edition)

Comment: Could you be missing some drivers or other pieces from your lowers to PROD or is it just the edition that is causing the problem?  If so you may be able to get around that by writing your own code in a C# script task instead of using the data flow task?

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap it in a linked server through another sql server, but I guess the idea is to actually force users to pay for the feature

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you and many others, the SSIS **Microsoft Connector for Oracle** requires SQL Server Enterprise or Developer editions on the SSIS run-time server.

> Required operating environment : Enterprise or Developer edition of
> SQL Server 2019 Integration Services, SQL Server 2022 Integration
> Services

For the reference: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104113